# $gte and $lte operators mongo filter string field by number

Tags: mongodb

I have a string field in MongoDB that contains years of experience, like '1 year', '3 years' etc.

I need to filter this field by number

```
db.collection.find({ experience: {'$gte': '1', 'lte': '3'} })
```

but it filters by string i.e. '$gte': '10' returns 3, 4, 7 etc., comparing strings.

I tried to create and index

```
db.profiles.createIndex( { experience: 1 }, { collation: { numericOrdering: true, locale: "en_US" } } )
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you also have values like `5 weeks` or `6 months`? Why do you store numeric values as string?

Comment: I am working with a legacy DB, I only need to create filters. It only has values with years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the string into a number, then you can filter on it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      regex: {
        $regexFind: {
          input: "$experience",
          regex: "^\\d+"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      experience_num: {
        $convert: {
          input: "$regex.match",
          to: "int"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {experience_num: {"$gte": 1, "$lte": 3}}},
  {$project: {experience: 1}}
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XNueZeBWVfJ)

1. Select just the number from the string
2. Convert the numeric string into an integer value
3. Filter by number >= 3 and <=1
4. Remove the extra attributes we have added

Comment: Thanks !! That's amazing answer. Can you add description of sequence you have added especially `$regex.match`